# Established Lua has different Interpreter?

Tags: lua, interpreter

I downloaded "LuaForWindows_v5.1.4-46.exe" with an IDE called SciTE.
But when I tried to excute

```
print(a)
```

a has not been assigned.When I use SciTE interactive Lua,the output is "variable 'qqqqqq' is not declared". 
Else if I open Cmd use

```
lua -e "print(aaaa)"
```

command  then output will be "nil",the same as I saw in book.

Who knows why different,cause Lua has different Interpreter??

Comment: Probably, SciTE Lua has some additional libraries integrated (such as `strict` library to prevent using undeclared variables)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same interpreter. Lua like C++ allows for 'function overloading'; the Scite IDE is overloading the print function during interactive sessions in order to provide for more human readable debug info. (A personal design decision by the Scite program authors.) The native Lua interpreter print function will output nil for the undeclared variable. When you run a Lua script in Scite, Scite will ensure your script sees the pure Lua interpreter behavior in all respects. In general with Lua IDE's like Scite, you will find they all try to add little helpers during design and debug, everthing from code completion to finding missing 'end' statement and so on. But rest assured when you hit that run button, the IDE will ensure your script sees nuthin but the lua.org released interpreter.

Comment: (*@ο@*)  WOW. Thank you very much!